# Spring security with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am making a *spring rest api* where I am using **JPA repository** and spring security but spring security should authenticate request using jdbc authenticater. I just want to check this on postman. All configuration is based on java.

**DBConfiguration class:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("com.bus.aqcuire.controller")
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.bus.aqcuire.repo")
public class DBConfiguration {

public DBConfiguration() {
        
    }

    @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
        {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Aquisition");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("root"); 
        
        return dataSource;
    }
```

**Application configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.bus.aqcuire.controller")
public class RestApplicationConfig{
    
}
```

**Spring Initializer**

```
public class RestApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DBConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RestApplicationConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("com.mphasis.aqcuire")
@Import(DBConfiguration.class)
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "Admin");
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I run the jar it even failed to start.

Here is the console log:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerBeansForRoot(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:166)
 ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
 org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:80)
 ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
 ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
 ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
 [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
 [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
> [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
> [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
 [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]  at
 com.bus.aqcuire.controller.App.main(App.java:21) [classes/:n

a]
```

I am also failing to make Spring **jdbc authenticater** where I can access api's if I am current logged in user

Comment: I removed Spring initializer and application config then also I am getting this error

Comment: I also tried removing complete spring-framework folder then added again build it still I am getting the same error. Please Help